# SQL - How would I find the latest trend in given data set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> Hi all, I have a table called DataTable and I have to extract the number of rows for each Area type. I am using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 
>   !Here This is the Table Script and sample data

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable
(Data_NId int, IUSNId int, Area_Name varchar(18), TimePeriod varchar(9), Data_Value int); 
INSERT INTO DataTable
([Data_NId], [IUSNId], [Area_Name], [TimePeriod], [Data_Value])
```

VALUES
    (74495, 133, 'Pashchim Champaran', '2010-2011', 73.2),
    (74496, 133, 'Kishanganj', '2010-2011', 71.9),
    (74497, 133, 'Katihar', '2010-2011', 75.9),
    (74498, 133, 'Saharsa', '2010-2011', 76.9),
    (74499, 133, 'Darbhanga', '2010-2011', 54.4),
    (74500, 133, 'Muzaffarpur', '2010-2011', 82.2),
    (74501, 133, 'Gopalganj', '2010-2011', 68.3),
    (74502, 133, 'Siwan', '2010-2011', 73.4),
    (74503, 133, 'Saran', '2010-2011', 56.4),
    (74504, 133, 'Vaishali', '2010-2011', 81.4),
    (74505, 133, 'Khagaria', '2010-2011', 84.8),
    (74506, 133, 'Bhagalpur', '2010-2011', 62.4),
    (74507, 133, 'Munger', '2010-2011', 87.1),
    (74508, 133, 'Lakhisarai', '2010-2011', 67.2),
    (74509, 133, 'Sheikhpura', '2010-2011', 78.5),
    (74510, 133, 'Nalanda', '2010-2011', 62.6),
    (74511, 133, 'Patna', '2010-2011', 88.5),
    (74512, 133, 'Bhojpur', '2010-2011', 88),
    (74513, 133, 'Buxar', '2010-2011', 69.8),
    (74514, 133, 'Rohtas', '2010-2011', 75.6),
    (74515, 133, 'Aurangabad', '2010-2011', 76.7),
    (74516, 133, 'Gaya', '2010-2011', 67.1),
    (74517, 133, 'Nawada', '2010-2011', 75.6),
    (74518, 133, 'Jehanabad', '2010-2011', 83.7),
    (74528, 133, 'Pashchim Champaran', '2011-2012', 74.1),
    (74529, 133, 'Kishanganj', '2011-2012', 82),
    (74530, 133, 'Katihar', '2011-2012', 80),
    (74531, 133, 'Saharsa', '2011-2012', 81.5),
    (74532, 133, 'Darbhanga', '2011-2012', 59.9),
    (74533, 133, 'Muzaffarpur', '2011-2012', 79.4),
    (74534, 133, 'Gopalganj', '2011-2012', 78.7),
    (74535, 133, 'Siwan', '2011-2012', 77),
    (74536, 133, 'Saran', '2011-2012', 62.3),
    (74537, 133, 'Vaishali', '2011-2012', 86.7),
    (74538, 133, 'Khagaria', '2011-2012', 85.9),
    (74539, 133, 'Bhagalpur', '2011-2012', 76.9),
    (74540, 133, 'Munger', '2011-2012', 81.4),
    (74541, 133, 'Lakhisarai', '2011-2012', 75.8),
    (74542, 133, 'Sheikhpura', '2011-2012', 84.7),
    (74543, 133, 'Nalanda', '2011-2012', 68.7),
    (74544, 133, 'Patna', '2011-2012', 88.4),
    (74545, 133, 'Bhojpur', '2011-2012', 86.4),
    (74546, 133, 'Buxar', '2011-2012', 73.4),
    (74547, 133, 'Rohtas', '2011-2012', 77.2),
    (74548, 133, 'Aurangabad', '2011-2012', 75.7),
    (74549, 133, 'Gaya', '2011-2012', 66.3),
    (74550, 133, 'Nawada', '2011-2012', 75.1),
    (74551, 133, 'Jehanabad', '2011-2012', 80.7),
    (74561, 133, 'Pashchim Champaran', '2012-2013', 79.1),
    (74562, 133, 'Kishanganj', '2012-2013', 81.9),
    (74563, 133, 'Katihar', '2012-2013', 83.3),
    (74564, 133, 'Saharsa', '2012-2013', 87),
    (74565, 133, 'Darbhanga', '2012-2013', 64.4),
    (74566, 133, 'Muzaffarpur', '2012-2013', 83.7),
    (74567, 133, 'Gopalganj', '2012-2013', 83.4),
    (74568, 133, 'Siwan', '2012-2013', 76.7),
    (74569, 133, 'Saran', '2012-2013', 64.9),
    (74570, 133, 'Vaishali', '2012-2013', 78.4),
    (74571, 133, 'Khagaria', '2012-2013', 87.6),
    (74572, 133, 'Bhagalpur', '2012-2013', 78),
    (74573, 133, 'Munger', '2012-2013', 84.8),
    (74574, 133, 'Lakhisarai', '2012-2013', 83.5),
    (74575, 133, 'Sheikhpura', '2012-2013', 82.4),
    (74576, 133, 'Nalanda', '2012-2013', 76.2),
    (74577, 133, 'Patna', '2012-2013', 89.7),
    (74578, 133, 'Bhojpur', '2012-2013', 86.9),
    (74579, 133, 'Buxar', '2012-2013', 76.3),
    (74580, 133, 'Rohtas', '2012-2013', 81.5),
    (74581, 133, 'Aurangabad', '2012-2013', 73.3),
    (74582, 133, 'Gaya', '2012-2013', 70.5),
    (74583, 133, 'Nawada', '2012-2013', 79.2),
    (74584, 133, 'Jehanabad', '2012-2013', 78.4)
;

> This is what I’m trying to obtain:

```
Data_NId   IUSNId       Area_Name        TimePeriod   Data_Value   P_Cange   Trend
```

---

```
 74495      133   Pashchim Champaran   2010-2011          73.2         5   P      
 74496      133   Kishanganj           2010-2011          71.9      -0.1   N      
 74497      133   Katihar              2010-2011          75.9       3.3   P      
 74498      133   Saharsa              2010-2011          76.9       5.5   P      
 74499      133   Darbhanga            2010-2011          54.4       4.5   P      
 74500      133   Muzaffarpur          2010-2011          82.2       4.3   P      
 74501      133   Gopalganj            2010-2011          68.3       4.7   P      
 74502      133   Siwan                2010-2011          73.4      -0.3   N      
 74503      133   Saran                2010-2011          56.4       2.6   P      
 74504      133   Vaishali             2010-2011          81.4      -8.3   N      
 74505      133   Khagaria             2010-2011          84.8       1.7   P      
 74506      133   Bhagalpur            2010-2011          62.4       1.1   P      
 74507      133   Munger               2010-2011          87.1       3.4   P      
 74508      133   Lakhisarai           2010-2011          67.2       7.7   P      
 74509      133   Sheikhpura           2010-2011          78.5      -2.3   N      
 74510      133   Nalanda              2010-2011          62.6       7.5   P      
 74511      133   Patna                2010-2011          88.5       1.3   P      
 74512      133   Bhojpur              2010-2011            88       0.5   P      
 74513      133   Buxar                2010-2011          69.8       2.9   P      
 74514      133   Rohtas               2010-2011          75.6       4.3   P      
 74515      133   Aurangabad           2010-2011          76.7      -2.4   N      
 74516      133   Gaya                 2010-2011          67.1       4.2   P      
 74517      133   Nawada               2010-2011          75.6       4.1   P      
 74518      133   Jehanabad            2010-2011          83.7      -2.3   N
```

> Note: - in Result table Data_Value shows by choosing any time period 
>   BUT in column (P_Cange ,Trend) always calculate the latest TimePeriod Data.
>   i have try so many concept but nothing works for me, my latest thought is if we could add a extra column for shorting time period like highest time period is 1 second highest time period is 2 so on ...... 
>   Now i am using this

```
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Area_Name ORDER BY Area_Name, TimePeriod DESC) AS RowNum from DataTable
```

> Thanks for the HELP

Comment: So you mean, you need the difference between Highest value and Second Highest value?

Comment: yes (Data Value of highest time Period) - (Data Value of Second Highest time Period) as percentage change

Comment: Is the "second highest value" _always_ less than the highest, or are they the top two values in descending order, even if they are equal? Have you tried anything? Any research? Any idea of what version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2, "second highest value" NOT always less than the highest. its not about the value its about the value in that time.

Comment: i have try it using Sub Query but its not working, using sub query  with MAX is only work with Single column

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Then edit your question so that it is clear, among other things, how _time_ is used in your desired calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you are trying to get the value what comes from "Highest Value - Second Highest Value" on particular column.

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX([col]) FROM [dbo].[YourTable]) - MAX([col])
  FROM [dbo].[YourTable]
 WHERE [col] < (SELECT MAX([col]) FROM [dbo].[YourTable])
```

Hope, this helps you.

Comment: Its not working, may be my question is not clear. i have refresh by query now